# How to get the active tab index with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the tabIndex value from the active paginate button.
my code :

```
<div
  class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers"
  id="usersUncalled_paginate"
>
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="paginate_button ">
      <a href="#" aria-controls="usersUncalled" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0"
        >1</a
      >
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button ">
      <a href="#" aria-controls="usersUncalled" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0"
        >2</a
      >
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button active">
      <a href="#" aria-controls="usersUncalled" data-dt-idx="3" tabindex="0"
        >3</a
      >
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button ">
      <a href="#" aria-controls="usersUncalled" data-dt-idx="4" tabindex="0"
        >4</a
      >
    </li>
  </ul>
</d
iv>
```

I want to get `3` the value of active button.

Comment: That's a simple class selector + `.text()`

Comment: `$('li.active a').html()` or `.text()`

Comment: If you want the `tabindex`: Don't hassle any longer and use `0`. If you want the `textContent` of the active anchor, use `$('.active').text()`.

Comment: Why do all the comments use `text()` when the OP want's the `tab-index`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Because the `tabindex` is always `0` but OP want's `3` for the `.active` element - and that's the text content of the `.active` node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the selector `li.active a` with jQuery's [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```js
var activeText = $('li.active a').attr('tabindex');
console.log(activeText);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div
  class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers"
  id="usersUncalled_paginate"
>
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="paginate_button ">
      <a href="#" aria-controls="usersUncalled" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="1"
        >1</a
      >
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button ">
      <a href="#" aria-controls="usersUncalled" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="2"
        >2</a
      >
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button active">
      <a href="#" aria-controls="usersUncalled" data-dt-idx="3" tabindex="3"
        >3</a
      >
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button ">
      <a href="#" aria-controls="usersUncalled" data-dt-idx="4" tabindex="4"
        >4</a
      >
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm confused. I thought the OP was asking for the active `tab-index`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, I was confused with the value set for *tabindex* (same for all), though updated the answer by setting different values:)

Comment: Thanks . I'm also confused why the OP cares about the tab-index when they're all the same in the code example.

Comment: @Mamun Thanks :D